# Importrange on google sheets showing data from days ago that's no longer there?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I have two Google Sheets set up.

**Master Roster, which has many sheets inside.**
Locale is Australia.

**Secondary Roster**, which has nothing but a sheet to grab data using import range.
Locale is Australia.

I'm using `=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<sheet ID>/edit", "Overview Frontend!A1:j15")`

Which was working fine yesterday! But, when viewing the sheet today, the data that importrange is showing is from the last time I used it yesterday.

If I remove the formula and then re-add it, it still grabs yesterdays data. If I view the master sheet, I can see the data has changed.

The data that is being displayed by import range doesn't exist anywhere?!

I even dropped in a script to re-pull the data, still shows stuff that is 24 hours old.

```
function myFunction() {
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange('A1').setValue('=Now()'); 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange('A1').setValue('=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<sheet ID>/edit", "Overview Frontend!A1:I16")');
```

Both sheets are set to refresh on change, but that doesn't seem to be the problem, as the data *is* changing and refreshing, but just isn't getting pulled across.

Comment: can you share copies/dummies of those sheets?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that it's a Google Sheets performance issue / bug or even that one your your spreadsheets is broken. Try to replicate the problem by using other new spreadsheets, one for Master Roster spreadsheet, another for the Secondary Roster spreadsheet. If the problem persist, report your issue both by using Google Feedback (Go to the Help menu, then click report a problem) and by making a post on the official Google Docs Help Forum / Community (go to https://support.google.com/docs then click on the Forum / Community link on the top-right of the page)

Comment: Well, this is odd.

I went to the gym, came back and it's updated 25 minutes ago... It went 24 hours without anything, then suddenly it's updated without me being at the PC.

Comment: @DeanSymons Belive it or not, this doesn't happen frequently but happens to several users once in a while. Maybe this time happens to you because Google is doing some changes on their data centers or software involved in providing the service to you.